# Alcuin's sequence and integer triangles of given perimeter

Tags: combinatorics

Alcuin's sequence is the sequence of coefficients in the expansion of $\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$ and begins $$0,0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,7,5,8,\dots$$
This is [A005044](https://oeis.org/A005044) in the OEIS, and according to it the $n$th term of the sequence is the number of *distinct* triangles with integer sides and perimeter $n$. For example, there are four triangles of perimeter 11:
$$(1,5,5),(2,4,5),(3,3,5),(3,4,4)$$
Why is this the case?

Comment: [Alcuin's Sequence on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin%27s_sequence).  Appears as [A005044 on OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005044).

Comment: I have taken the liberty of rewriting your question, as it is an interesting one to me that I too would like to know the answer to.  The basic information of what it is I included in the post which can also be found in the above links.  Please try to include more context in the future and use more precise grammar (*the question was almost unreadable in its original form*).

Comment: The coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)}$ is the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, $b\geq 1$ and $2a+3b+4c=n$.

Comment: Such number behaves like $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{48}$ (due to the triple pole at $x=1$) plus a small arithmetic perturbation (due to other poles).

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_i$ $(1\leq i\leq 3)$ be the sides such triangles. Then we want
$$1\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_1+a_2-1\ ,\tag{1}$$
since these triangles should be nondegenerate. It follows that the numbers
$$y_1:=a_1+a_2-a_3-1,\quad y_2:=a_2-a_1,\quad y_3:=a_3-a_2\tag{2}$$
are nonnegative integers. Solving $(2)$ for the $a_i$ gives
$$a_1=1+y_1+y_3,\quad a_2=1+y_1+y_2+y_3,\quad a_3=1+y_1+y_2+2y_3\ ,\tag{3}$$
so that $(1)$ is automatically fulfilled when $y_i\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, and more: The admissible triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ are bijectively related to the admissible triples $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

From $(3)$ it follows that the circumference $n$ of the triangle determined by the triple $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is given by
$$n=3+3y_1+2y_2+4y_3\ .\tag{4}$$
The number of different triangles with given circumference $n\in{\mathbb N}$ is therefore equal to the number of solutions of $(4)$ in nonnegative integers $y_i$. It is a standard fact from generatingfunctionology that this number is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the formal power series of
$$F(x):={x^3\over(1-x^3)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume $(a,b,c)$ is a triangle iff $a,b,c \ge 1, b \ge a, c \ge b$ and $a+b > c$.

Let's do a change of coordinates, and write $x=b-a, y=c-b, z=a+b-c$.
Then you can check that
$(a,b,c) = x*(0,1,1) + y*(1,1,2) + z*(1,1,1)$.

Now if you translate the conditions in terms of $x,y,z$, you get :
$y+z \ge 1, x+y+z \ge 1, x+2y+z \ge 1$,
$x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 1$.

This is equivalent to simply $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 1$.

Therefore, you can build all the triangles by starting with $(1,1,1)$ and adding any number of $(0,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,1)$ you want.

Since the "perimeter" of those pieces are $2,4,3$, there are as many triangles of perimeter $n$ as ways to write $n=3+2x+4y+3z$ for some $x,y,z \ge 0$.